# Delete a concrete element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags, closest

I think that's a very simple question, but I can't deal with it: I have an unordered list in my jsp with some list items like these:

```
<li>
    <p class="text">Some text.</p>
    <table class="answer-details" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tr">
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="msg-modification" display="inline" align="right">
                    <a id="modify" class="delete-answer" href="#">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: bottom;">
                <img src="...">
                <a class="answer-author" href="..." target="_blank">User name</a>
                <div class="answer-info">29/06/2011</div>
            </td>
        </tr>                               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, every list item has a link to delete the message/answer. What I'm trying to do is, using jQuery, show an information message into the same li when I click the link, and delete all the content into the list item except that message.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.esborrar-resposta').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('.li').children('p').remove(); // it doesn't work
    $(this).closest('.tr').before('<tr><td><div class="output">Information message</div></td></tr>');
    $(this).closest('.tr').remove();
});
```

The above code deletes all except the paragraph tag. This is my resulting HTML code:

```
<li>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <table class="answer-details" style="width: 100%">
            <tbody>
                    <tr><td><div class="output">Information message</div></td></tr>                             
            </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
```

I want to delete this paragraph tag, but I tried these options with no luck:

```
$(this).closest('.li').children('p').remove();
```

and

```
$(this).closest('.text').remove()
```

(Maybe it doesn't work because the paragraph tag is not a parent of link tag)

Can someone help me to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
$(this).closest('.li').children('p').remove();
```

Searches for an element with class `li`, not a `<li>` element. Replace with:

```
$(this).closest('li').children('p').remove();`
```

---

```
$(this).closest('.text').remove()
```

Will not work, since `.closest()` does the following:

> Get the first **ancestor element** that matches the selector, beginning at
>   the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree. (my emphasis)

The `p.text` element is not an ancestor, but a sibling to an ancestor. Thus, the following might have worked:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.text').remove();
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking about the closest method. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("li")
```

instead of

```
$(".li")


$(this).closest('li').children('p').remove();
```

because `.`li (that leading dot) means you'Re searching for `class="li"`, not`<li>` itself

Comment: Wow! What a big mistake! It works now. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

li is not a class  `$(this).closest('.li').children('p').remove();`

use `$(this).closest('li').children('p').remove();`